# How to define "selected" option of select that serves as AngularJS filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am pretty experienced with Javascript and jQuery, but I am a total noob with regards to AngularJS.

Currently I am filling my model from an $http.get, so in the beginning (after page load) the model is empty.

The view for the model is a table, and I use a `<select>` element to filter this table as follows:

```
<select ng-model="herkunftFilter.herkunft">
  <option value="BTRG">BTRG</option>
  <option value="BTRGMA">BTRGMA</option>
  <option value="DBLATT">DBLATT</option>
  <option value="DBLATTMA">DBLATTMA</option>
</select>
```

This is the controller. I *think* it all comes down to applying a specific filter here ... but how do I do that??

```
    var monitoringViewApp = angular.module('monitoringViewApp', []);
    monitoringViewApp.controller('MonitoringCtrl', function ($scope, $http){
        $http.get('api/getmonitorview').success(function(data) {
            $scope.monitoringTasks = data;
            // set the filter herkunftFilter.herkunft to be 'BTRG'
            // but HOW?
        });
    });
```

With this construct I wanted to preselect the first `herkunft` content of the data model as the `selected` option of the `<select>` element, so that the filter doesn't start empty.

But it is empty ... what do I need to do?

The `<select>` works as a filter for these table rows:

```
<tr ng-repeat="task in monitoringTasks | filter:herkunftFilter:true">
    <td style="display: none;">{{task.herkunft}}</td>
    <td style="width: 50%">{{task.task}}</td>
    <td>{{task.countEingang}}</td>
    <td>{{task.countInArbeit}}</td>
    <td>{{task.countFehler}}</td>
</tr>
```

Any suggestions as on how can I set a `selected` option after my model has loaded, so that the filter automatically applies and doesn't stay empty?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
 <select  ng-model="selectedherkunftFilter"
 ng-options="monitoringTasks.herkunft for monitoringTask in  monitoringTasks">      
 <option ng-if="!selectedherkunftFilter" value="">Select Value</option>    
 </select>
```

Comment: It doesn't work like that. The goal seems to be to apply a specific filter in the $http.get callback (success) ... but how?